# Need to make a condition to update csv file ( condition: when it reads specific word it remove line before this word with python )

Tags: python, csv, conditional-statements

I have a csv file and i want to read it with python.

I want to put a condition that says: when it reads the word ‘layer2id’ on the beginning of the line and on the first column it erases the lines before.

Comment: Please show us what code you have so far.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.